# Why add extra resistance to a shunt?

Tags: current, current-measurement, measurement, shunt

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5XKWa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm using a **Fluke Y5020** air cooled shunt (it's 10 mΩ, 20 A max) and putting 3 A at 60 Hz into it.

- Aside from Ohm's law, is there any particular reason I would need to add resistance in series (I had a 50 Ω max rheostat in series) through the current input into the Fluke Y5020?
  (I couldn't get this particular shunt to work otherwise like a normal shunt, just hook up and go, sorry no pic.)
- I'm using a 34401A to read the mV. (I realize this is only 10 MΩ which is not enough for this shunt, that's why my mV readings initially looked bad.)

Some circuit analysis with diagram would be great.

The [manual](https://userequip.com/files/specs/223/FLUKE%20Y5020%20Instruction.pdf) says  **Accurate current measurements require the use of a
highimpedance (>10 MΩ) digital voltmeter to measure the
shunt voltage appearing at the OUTPUT TERMINALS."**

Comment: At 10 mΩ you're going to get 100 mV/A from the shunt. What do you mean by, "*I realize this is only 10 MΩ which is not enough for this shunt*"?

Comment: I was thinking this as well but it didn't give me any output that made sense until I had hooked up a rheostat in series with the current input...

Comment: Putting a 10 MΩ voltmeter in parallel to a 0.01 Ω  shunt will reduce the resistance by 0.000,000,000,010 Ω. Does that matter to you?

Comment: 10pΩ how did you get this.... if you don't mind.....

Comment: @Doug 10 MΩ in parallel with 10 mΩ = 9,999999990 mΩ, which is 10 pΩ less.

Comment: @Doug - Hi, Your question (which I *think* is something like - why did you *apparently* need to add a 50 Ω rheostat in series with the shunt for it to "work") seems to be mixed with your concerns about the voltmeter impedance requirements (where you seem to be saying that a 10 MΩ voltmeter isn't suitable). If your main question is why you apparently needed a series resistance, please [edit] your question & add more details of what happened without that series resistance. Can you reproduce the "not working" situation again please, then supply photos? (I know you said you don't have any now.) TY

Comment: Additionally to what Sam mentioned, an expression like *"my mV readings initially looked bad"* leaves us in the dark about what actually is happening. Try to describe the setup in more precise terms, what you expected and what you got as measurements.

Comment: @Doug - As *Davide Andrea* has kindly pointed out in an [answer](/a/648455) (and I had totally missed when writing my earlier comment), your schematic is missing a load through which you are trying to measure the current. So the point in that answer doesn't get lost, I'll ask it here as a clarification comment: What is the *real* load in your experiment? If there really isn't another one, then the 50 Ω rheostat *is* the load - but then there's no reason to be concerned that it's needed. Please clarify your intended experiment *in detail* and what you are trying to measure. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for responding, initially I was expecting output of (roughly) 30.0045 mV with R=10mΩ (shunt load) and then ohms law I=V/R to get my answer.  just trying to understand the problem, I was thinking that the shunt resistance (10mΩ) was "the load" and that it would be enough by itself to get a measurement.....that's where I'm going wrong.  I think most of our other shunts have around a 100 mΩ resistance, is it just that the 10mΩ is just too small to act as a proper load? (depending on what type of current I put into it)

Answer (score 5):

> Is there any particular reason I would need to add resistance in series

Yes. That "added resistance" is the load whose current you wish to measure. Without that load, a) the shunt acts as a short circuit across the voltage source, with dire consequences; and b) what's the point of the measurement if there's no load, which is what you wanted to measure in the first place?

> I'm using a 34401A [voltmeter] to read the mV

That voltmeter has an input resistance of 10 MΩ. That's **nine** orders of magnitude more than the shunt resistance. That means that the meter will have no discernible effect on the reading. You're fine.

Comment: Thank You, that's why I was baffled by the 34401A....

Answer (score 3):

From [here](https://www.stratatek.com/product-page/fluke-y5020-precision-current-shunt-ac-dc-shunt-20a-5khz-1) is a photo of the same part number Fluke shunt:

[image]

As you can see, it's about 0.01Ω, so the 10MΩ input impedance of the 34401A will not load the shunt significantly, even to the 6 digit resolution of the DMM.

The shunt appears to be isolated from ground (though they recommend no more than 20V RMS between shunt and earth ground, probably for legal liability/safety reasons).

[Here](https://userequip.com/files/specs/223/FLUKE%20Y5020%20Instruction.pdf) is the manual and you can see that it's a rather simple circuit:

[image]

So there's no reason this would not work as an ordinary shunt, since that's all it is. It's up to you to limit the current through the shunt to an appropriate level and that would typically involve both the source voltage and the load resistance.
And typically the load resistance would be >> 0.01Ω so as to minimize the effect of the shunt on the overall circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZ1D3S.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Here the voltage source is 12VAC RMS so the voltage across the shunt resistor is about 2mV RMS since the total load resistance is 6.01Ω.